# My NodeJS route not inserting proper values into table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, routes

I'm new to using node with MySQL but when I tried sending a query to my SQL server to insert the data it wasn't inserting the values from the form submitted. My route code looks like this,

```
const { application } = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router() 
const pool = require('../config/db');

router.post("/create", async (req, res) => {

  
  // Get user input
  const  name = req.body.name
  const  country = req.body.country
  const  dob = req.body.dob

    const sql = `INSERT INTO users (name, country, dob) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"', '"+req.body.country+"','"+req.body.dob+"');`
  pool.query(sql, function(error, results){
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    res.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.id}`)
    console.log(name);
  })


   
});
```

my query previously was like this,

```
const sql = `INSERT INTO users (name, country, dob) VALUES (name, country, dob);`
```

But both are not working as far as I'm trying to insert them into the table.
Some important code from my React Form which might help,

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.options = countryList().getData();

this.state = {
   name: '',
   options: this.options,
   val: null,
   country: '',
   dob: new Date(),
}

this.handleStartDateChange = this.handleStartDateChange.bind(this);
  }



 handleNameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  handleOptionsChange = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      val
    })
    this.setState({
      country:val.label
    })
  }

  
  handleStartDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      dob: date
    })
  }
```

My handle submit is like this,

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/create', this.state)
    console.log(this.state);
```

console.log(this.state) gives this in the console after submitting,

```
{name: 'Prajwal V', options: Array(249), val: {…}, country: 'Afghanistan', dob: Wed Nov 09 2022 18:02:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
country
: 
"Afghanistan"
dob
: 
Wed Nov 09 2022 18:02:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name
: 
"Prajwal V"
options
: 
(249) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
val
: 
{value: 'AF', label: 'Afghanistan'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

The table contents in PHPMyAdmin[image],

I hope I've clearly explained my questions. Thank you so much on reviewing this.

Comment: Can you please add error message? And did you hit api through postman and check for the result ?

Comment: @VivekRahul thank you for pointing this out, I've updated my questions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the query in your API. Also, you need to go back and do a SELECT to get the id of the row you are wanting to send back to your front end.

```js
const { application } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require("../config/db");

router.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
  // Get user input
  const { name, country, dob } = req.body;

  pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO users SET name = ?, country = ?, dob = ?",
    [name, country, dob],
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        pool.query(
          "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?, country = ?, cob = ?",
          [name, country, dob],
          (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            } 
            if (results) {
              res.status(200).send(`User added with ID: ${results.id}`);
              console.log(name);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Also, make sure your datatypes are correct in your database otherwise MySQL will reject the values you provide.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. But can you explain why this works?

Comment: Sure. If you declare req.body as a constant, it gives you flexibility (you were declaring each value for the MySQL query individually. By using placeholder syntax "name = ?, country = ?" etc, you can list the values you want inserted in the array that follows the MySQL statement -> [name, country...]. FYI, the array must follow the same order as the query itself. The first "?" in the statement gets filled with the value from the first value in the array. @PrajwalAbraham